# url of the workspace from a jenkins-pipeline, in the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I configure my jenkinsPipeline with a jenkinsFile. It generate log

I want to print the url of a file build in the workspace during the job. Not the path in the machine, the url.

How can I have the url of the current workspace, dynamically in my jenkinsFile?

Comment: You can't directly link to files in the workspace. Use the `archive` step, which should allow you to have a predictable path then.

Comment: @StephenKing

I found no doc for archive, but I found archiveArtifacts, is-it that?
Also, will it work on branch?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: With multi-branch, every branch is just a separate job.

Comment: show code sample you use, so others can post code to support you directly

Comment: files in workspace can be lost in next build, if you want to access the file, archive it first. If you really want to stick with your current workspace, that is different, clarify in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using env variable BUILD_URL in JenkinsFile

Comment: I have try, It don't work: it give only the job url, and in a pipeline, it's not enought to fins the workspace url.